# Neural networks and unordered input data

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

Much work has been done in recent years on neural networks where the input is a collection. In particular, convolutional networks often work well on N-dimensional arrays (exploiting spatial structure) and recurrent neural networks such as LSTM often work well on time-series data (exploiting temporal structure).

I'm currently looking at the question of using neural networks for heuristic guidance of search in theorem proving. One of the problems here is that the input takes the form not of an array but of a set of clauses, where there is not so much of a natural ordering between clauses, and we cannot say that each clause will mostly interact with nearby neighbors in space.

Aside from 'bag of words' for text documents (which works because there is a fixed dictionary), is anything already known about which neural network architectures work well for inputs that don't have a natural order?